# Making a login screen for my iphone app

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

im facing some difficulties making a login screen for my app. First of all im a noobie around this... im actually creating this a form of learning... my app is a simple calculator... so...
 first thing i need to know is: Which template should i use for this kind of app (one that has multiple views)
second is: how can implement a new view?
third: How do i transit between views?

the big point here is not the login screen but the transition between views! Thank you all for the support!

ps: im using the latest version of xcode and iOS dev libs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see [this sample](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Xcode_Storyboarding_%28iPhone_iOS_5%29) to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at the [Stanford iOS Lectures](https://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-sd/id395631522) (Available for free download) in iTunes U. There's actually an example of a Calculator app in Lecture 2. It's a good place to start.

Comment: i got the calculator part cover... i want the login screen and the multiple views part!

Comment: Then watch the lectures, there's 25 of them. As soon as you learn how to handle multiple view controllers, you'll know how to do what you want.